# How can I convert to text I collect from these input fields to lower case in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to convert any text that the user inputs in the following input fields to lower case how can I do that?

```
//collect the input fields
inputs = secWidget.getInputs();
inputs2 = secWidget2.getInputs();
```

Comment: What does your `.getInputs()` function return?

Comment: these are very simple things and can be found directly using google search

Comment: @Sandeepan - I disagree it's *as simple* as the answerers seem to think, the naming alone implies it's returning a *collection* of inputs each time.

Comment: @Nick - then is there any answer other than applying `toLoweCase()` to the output? so as to directly get the lower case values? If not this is as simple as searching "javascript lower case" in google. I said it simple because you get the exact answer in the top few results by searching the sentence you have phrased from your problem

Comment: @Nick makes a good point. While `toLowerCase` may be *part* of the answer, it doesn't seem to fully answer the question. I wonder if OP is using the [getInputs()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/getInputs) method from `prototypejs`.

Comment: @patrick dw: Answer was given with respect to provided info :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - Yes indeed. :o) It would be good if OP answered the first comment and provided more information.

Comment: @Nick I see your point now `getInputs()` means a collection of inputs. Sorry for that. I should observe more carefully now onwards. Thanks @patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming those methods return array of values, here is the most straightforward way to achive what you asked:

```
inputs = secWidget.getInputs();
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
   inputs[i] = inputs[i].toLowerCase();
```

If still no luck please post more code and explain what getInputs return.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`toLowerCase`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) function of javascript for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
//collect the input fields
inputs = secWidget.getInputs().toLowerCase();
inputs2 = secWidget2.getInputs().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `toLowerCase` string method in Javascript.
Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLowerCase.asp

use:
`inputs = secWidget.getInputs().toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1):

you can use toLowerCase as mentioned above and toLocaleLowerCase() which in turn takes current locale of the user/host into account

Comment: I keep getting an error in firebug that sayss this is not a function

Comment: are you using toLowerCase  or toLocaleLowerCase ?

Comment: where are you trying to do this ? in HTML code or code behind in c# ?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `toLowerCase()` will do what you want to do. *However*, I would also do this in code behind the scenes. You should always validate these inputs server-side, assuming this data is being processed in any way.

Users will always be able to disable javascript.